# Does disposing a CryptoStream flush the final block?

Tags: .net, encryption, stream, using, cryptostream

From the Microsoft .NET API the following information can be extracted:

- `using` will call the implementation of `IDisposable.Dispose()`;
- `IDisposable.Dispose()` should call `Flush()` on any `Stream` instance;
- `CryptoStream.Close()` will call `CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()`.

However, this seems to leave a gap in the specification: will disposing of a `CryptoStream` instance also call `CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()`, and if so, where is this documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dispose()` calls `FlushFinalBlock()` if it has not already been called. This is also in the documentation, however not centrally, but distributed:

`CryptoStreams` does not overload `Close()` or the (parameterless) public `Dispose()`, so the implementations of the `Stream` class are called.

The documentation of [`Stream#Dispose()` (s. Remarks)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.dispose?view=netframework-4.8) states:

> This method disposes the stream, by writing any changes to the backing store and closing the stream to release resources.

This is consistent with the source code (from .NET Framework 4.8). [`Stream#Dispose()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,252) calls `Stream#Close()`.

The documentation of [`CryptoStream#FlushFinalBlock()` (s. Remarks)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) says (as already described by you):

> Calling the Close method will call FlushFinalBlock.

This is again consistent with the source code (from .NET Framework 4.8). [`Close()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,240) calls (among other things) the protected (virtual) overload `Dispose(true)`, which is overridden in `CryptoStream`, see [`CryptoStream#Dispose(bool disposing)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptostream.cs,701), and which calls `FlushFinalBlock()` if it has not already been called (i.e. depending on `_finalBlockTransformed`),

These details are described in [`CryptoStream#Dispose(Boolean)` (s. Remarks)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.dispose?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> This method is called by the public Dispose() method and the Finalize method. Dispose() invokes the protected Dispose(Boolean) method with the disposing parameter set to true...

Comment: Thank you for this pretty definitive answer, this should be a great go-to Q/A when people insist of having the user call `FlushFinalBlock` while the code in the question is already using `using` :)